# Not able to connect rabbitmq deployed on azure container app

Tags: node.js, azure

I am able to successfully deploy rabbitmq on azure container app using rabbitmq:3-mangement image , and able to see the rabbitmq UI on deployed URL
however from code I am not able to connect in node js when I am using amqp lib , below is the sample code I am trying to use , could someone help what I am missing?

```
  async createChannel() {
const connection = await amqp.connect("amqp://rabbitmq-server.politepebble-2d61dcba.centralindia.azurecontainerapps.io");

console.log('connection established');
this.channel = await connection.createChannel();
```

}

[image]
[image]

Comment: please share the DockerFile and docker.yml

Comment: I am trying to connect from local machine , and since  I enabled ingress and selected accept traffic from anywhere I should be able to access  rabbit  mq server deployed via local server/machine just like able to access rabbit mq server UI , once I am able to connect it locally would deploy node service to container app as well

Comment: RabbitMQ is an open-source distributed message broker that facilitates efficient message delivery in complex routing scenarios. Azure Container Apps is a serverless platform that allows you to maintain less infrastructure and save costs while running containerized [applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/start-containers)

Comment: Yeah I know that is why I am trying to use it,  but from my local node server I was expecting to have successful connection to rabbitmq deployed in azure container app but it is showing error

Comment: Where did you get the `amqp` URL and How did you convert it

Comment: I used it from application url from portal as you can see the image I added above

Comment: Getting error as below  rror  Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 20.204.189.140:5672
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1494:16) {
  errno: -4039,
  code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '20.204.189.140',
  port: 5672
}
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 20.204.189.140:5672
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1494:16)
[ERROR] 15:32:17 Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 20.204.189.140:5672

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256420/discussion-between-sampath-and-vaibhav-mittal).

Comment: ok sure joining now